# Create an NSDictionary containing several NSArrays

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

I want to unite several NSArrays into one NSDictionary.
Here are my arrays:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *EuropeTable;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *AsiaTable;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *AfricaTable;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *LatinAmericaTable;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *NorthAmericaTable;
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

***EDIT**

I want each array to have the same key @"country", so that I could use this single key later

Comment: Please add more details. Do you want each arran to be a single element in the dictionary, each array has its own key and the value is the array or do you expect all the elements of all arrays to be in the directly in the dictionary. In this case, each element needs its own key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictionary setObject:self.EuropeTable forKey:@"EuropeTable"];
[dictionary setObject:self.AsiaTable forKey:@"AsiaTable"];
[dictionary setObject:self.AfricaTable forKey:@"AfricaTable"];
[dictionary setObject:self.LatinAmericaTable forKey:@"LatinAmericaTable"];
[dictionary setObject:self.NorthAmericaTable forKey:@"NorthAmericaTable"];
```

Then to access one of the arrays you need to:

```
NSArray *europeTable = [dictionary objectForKey:@"EuropeTable"];
```

**UPDATE:**

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.EuropeTable,
                                           self.AsiaTable,
                                           self.AfricaTable, 
                                           self.LatinAmericaTable,
                                           self.NorthAmericaTable, nil];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:array forKey:@"country"];
```

Comment: NSDictionary is a better choice to use unless you need to modify the Dictionary after creation.  deanWombourne's answer is more efficient in this case.

Comment: +1 for not 'knocking' the poster (unlike some) when there was no need. Agree with ElJay about efficiency comment

Comment: Then you need an array, add all arrays inside, and create a dictionary with 1 object (this array) with the key @"country".

Comment: @ElJay - though I make the assumption that none of the objects are `nil` - Personally, I'd use the mutable method in the answer above and then copy it when I'm done to make it immutable to use later.

Comment: @deanWombourne, why would you create a MutableDictionary only to just copy it to a Immutable one?  Doesn't this just add additional memory usage and object allocation when it isn't needed?

Comment: In my answer, I pass in all the arrays in the constructor. However, if the any of the arrays is `nil`, all the ones after it don't get added :( The way to fix this is to use the answer above and use a mutable dictionary to create it initially. However, once it's created, I don't ever want to change it so I make it immutable. Assuming that I'm only ever doing this once on startup I'd rather have the safer code; if I were doing this a lot, I wouldn't bother and would just use the mutable one.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDictionary *countries =
  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    EuropeTable, @"You",
    AsiaTable, @"Need To",
    AfricaTable, @"Provide",
    LatinAmericaTable @"More",
    NorthAmericaTable, @"Details",
    nil];
```

Without more details, I'm not sure any answer will help you much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict addObject:self.EuropeTable forKey:@"EuropeTable"];
etc...
```